# Apply CSS to printed links

Tags: html, css

I have some links that are in black text. Based on what the user selects in a drop down, I apply the below CSS to change matching links. If the user then selects to print the view they are looking those same links print out in black text. How can I get the CSS to carry over to a printed view so the user sees the same color printed as they see on the screen?

```
$this.find('a').css("color", "#bfbfbf");
$this.find('.fa-play').css("color", "#bfbfbf");
$this.find('.fa-check-circle').css("color", "#bfbfbf");
```

Comment: [Use a stylesheet, and wrap those styles in `@media print { ... }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) -- you can't use media queries with inline styles, however.

Comment: Does the user have limited options in your dropdown? You may have to have a separate stylesheet and add classes as well as changing the css.

Comment: @Blazemonger the OP may be asking a different question as the values are changing in the markup based on the selection.

Comment: @disinfor OP needs to explain that, then.

Comment: @disinfor the affected links change color based on the value selected in the drop down. So, if I have 100 links and the user picks Value1 in the drop down, 10 of those links might change color.

Comment: @Wannabe yes, but how many options does the user have? That could determine the solution.

Comment: @disinfor the user has a configurable number of options. In reality, it will be between 5 to 10 options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will affect the CSS of any element inside while being in print mode:

```
@media print {
   span {
      color: black;
   }
}
```

in the above example, any span's color will be black on print mode.

**Edit: 28 Oct 2017**
Based on comments @TamirNahum suggested, I have figured this out. Below is the complete answer.

The jQuery .addClass will inject the class 'tailoredLink' into the each element that matches the dropdown selection.

```
$this.find('a').css("color", "#bfbfbf").addClass("tailoredLink");
$this.find('.fa-play').css("color", "#bfbfbf").addClass("tailoredLink");
$this.find('.fa-check-circle').css("color", "#bfbfbf").addClass("tailoredLink");
```

Then when the user chooses to print the page, the following CSS will show the "Tailored Links" in gray.

```
@media print {
   .tailoredLink{
      color: gray;
   }
}
```

Comment: This may not work, because the value is changing dynamically based on what the user picks. Or that at least appears to be the case.

Comment: I would use it with some jQuery code to set a class of the selected color. For example, if the user selects 'red' - a 'red' class will be added to the 'body' element.
And then, into CSS I'd do:
@media print { .red span { color: black } }

Comment: Yes, see my original comment on the question. You should add the jQuery to your answer if you want it to be complete.

Comment: Right, the links that are affected can change depending on what criteria the user selects in the drop down.

Comment: @TamirNahum that sounds like what I want. I'll try it and report back.

Comment: Apologies for taking a long time to get back to this, but based on your comments, I have figured it out and updated the answer for how I got it working.